# Proof of Cartan lemmma : why are the coefficients smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am new to differential geometry and I am struggling on the proof of the Cartan's lemma. The version I am trying to prove is the following.

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold, $\omega^1,...,\omega^k,\alpha^1,...,\alpha^k$ be smooth 1-forms such that

1. The $(\omega^i)$ are linearly independant
2. $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^i \wedge \omega^i= 0$.

Then the $(\alpha^i)$ are smooth linear linear combinations of the $(\omega^i)$.

I don't see how to prove the "smooth" part.

Here is how I managed to prove the fact that each $\alpha^i$ is linearly generated by the $(\omega^i)$. In the second assumption take the wedge product with $\omega^1 \wedge ... \wedge \omega^{k-1}$ to get
$$
\alpha^k \wedge \omega^k \wedge \omega^1 \wedge ... \wedge \omega^{k-1} = 0.
$$
I know that for covectors this means they are linearly dependant, so for all $p \in M$, $\alpha_p^1 , \omega^1_p,...,\omega^k_p$ are linearly dependant. Let $\lambda, \mu_1,...,\mu_k$ be reals not all null such that
$$
\lambda \alpha_p^k + \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i\omega_p^i = 0.
$$
We cannot have $\lambda = 0$ because then by the first assumption $\lambda = \mu_1 = ... = \mu_k = 0$. That is $\alpha_p^k \in \langle \omega_p^i \rangle_{i=1}^k$.

The same work can be done up to a change of index to prove that $\alpha_p^i \in \langle \omega_p^i \rangle_{i=1}^k$ for $i = 1,...,k$ arbitrary.

Now I don't know how to prove the coefficients are smooth, my idea would be to get a formula and see if it is smooth on $p$ but I don't see how to perform this operation.

Any hint in this direction, or a general fact about differential geometry that guaranty the coefficients to be smooth, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, I think the only "issue" is that you're losing a tiny bit of information at the step where you say "I know that for covectors this means [...]".

The $2$ hypotheses for Cartan's lemma are true for **differential forms**, but at that step, you're only proving it for covectors (*ie*, for differential forms restricted to one point of your manifold). So you lose the information of what's going on "around $p$".

While, actually, if you start with a smooth $1$-form $\omega$ on a manifold, it can be written locally as $\omega = \displaystyle\sum g_i \mathrm{d}x_i$ where the $g_i$ are smooth functions, and the $\{\mathrm{d}x_i\}$ form a local basis for the cotangent bundle (= a **coframe**, if you want a good explanation on this, check [Prop. 11.18 of Intro to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ejchaidez/materials/reu/lee_smooth_manifolds.pdf)).

Then, your reasoning still holds, except now in the expression $\lambda \alpha^k + \displaystyle\sum_i \mu_i \omega^i$, the coefficients $\lambda$ and $\mu_i$ are smooth functions defined locally around $p$, instead of being scalars. Then, since you're only doing some basic operations on these sums to express each $\alpha$ in the $\{\omega\}$ basis, everything stays smooth :).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If I understand well you are telling me that I should use the $(\omega^i)$ to get a local basis of $T^*M$, then one for $\Lambda^1(T^*M)$ and argue that a smooth 1-form has smooth coordinates no matter what is the local basis we use. Is that it?

Comment: Also we might have a problem in case $k < n$. I think we can remove this problem by smoothly complete $(\omega^i)$.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Once you have a (local) basis for $T*M$ (which we usually take to be the "standard" basis, ie the one dual to the local basis for $TM$), then a smooth form is a "smooth" linear combination of this basis :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting approach that I've never seen or thought of before. Here is a sketch of the standard approach, from which smoothness is a standard argument.

The lemma is this: Locally you can extend $\omega^1,\dots,\omega^k$ to a smooth *basis* of $1$-forms. (For example, in local coordinates, some choice of complementary set $dx^{j_1},\dots,dx^{j_{n-k}}$ will do it.)

Now write $\alpha^i = \sum_{j=1}^n f^i_j\omega^j$. The second condition allows you to see that $f^i_j = 0$ for $j>k$. Now argue directly that in this situation the $f^i_j$ must be smooth functions. (This boils down, again, in local coordinates, to the fact that the inverse of a smooth matrix function is smooth and the product of smooth functions is smooth.)